# Suggestions on ways to store file information using python

Tags: python

I've been looking around online for ways to store information in python and i came across a variety of ways to do this. I wanted to come to stackoverflow and see what you guys 'who are more experienced with python' would suggest in this scenario.

I'm doing a for-loop collecting all the files in a specific directory. What I want to do is collect each file along with it's file size, filename, and filetype. What would you guys recommend for this? The method used below i know is not good practice.

```
import os

cacheDir = os.path.normpath('Q:\Qoros\Project_Assets\car\PublishedMXS')
mxsFiles = []
mxsNames = []
maxFilesize = []

for file in os.listdir(cacheDir):
    if file.endswith(".mxs"):
        filePath = cacheDir + '/' + file
        prefix = file.split('_')

        mxsFiles.append(filePath)
        mxsNames.append(prefix[0])
        # maxFilesize.append(filesize)
```

Comment: How do you intend to use this information once you've got it?

Comment: [The standard pickle module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) can be helpful if both the writer and reader are python scripts.

Comment: I'll use to in a dialog im creating that generates a list of items based on filetype for importing into 3dsMax and Maya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import namedtuple
import glob
import os

cache_dir = os.path.normpath('Q:\Qoros\Project_Assets\car\PublishedMXS')
filespec  = "*.mxs"

FileData = namedtuple("FileData", ["name", "prefix", "size"])

files = []
for fname in glob.glob(os.path.join(cache_dir, filespec)):
    name = os.path.abspath(fname)
    prefix = fname.split("_")[0]
    size = os.stat(fname).st_size
    files.append(FileData(name, prefix, size))
```

Comment: very clever approach. I was unaware of being able to do named tuples. Thats is very interesting. Thank you Hugh for the suggested answer. I'm going to have to check this out.